# I want to increase countoftask of category when a task of that category is inserted in task table

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_task_forinsert
AFTER INSERT ON task for each row
BEGIN
    SET @count = (select countoftask from category where catid = NEW.catid and userid=NEW.userid);

    UPDATE category 
    SET countoftask = @count+1 
    WHERE catid=NEW.catid and userid=NEW.userid;
END
```

where is the error?

task TABLE

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| taskid   | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| taskname | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| catid    | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| userid   | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| taskdate | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| tasktime | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

CATEGORY TABLE

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| catid       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| catname     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| userid      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | 0       |                |
| countoftask | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Don't be shy.  Include the error that you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to fetch the value into a variable, but that won't cause an error.  This is a simpler form:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tr_task_forinsert
AFTER INSERT ON task for each row
BEGIN
    UPDATE category 
    SET countoftask = countoftask + 1 
    WHERE catid = NEW.catid and userid = NEW.userid;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Your problem might just be delimiters.